# What does it mean to "serve traffic" in SQL?

Tags: sql

I'm a translator and reviewer, also passionate and learning about IT, and I'd like to know what the verb "serve" means in SQL, specifically "to serve traffic". This verb is kind of tricky for me and I can think of two opposite definitions: to make traffic available (like "offer") and to "respond" to traffic requests (as in serve a request, maybe?). If my assumptions are total nonsense, please let me know. If someone could clarify this, It would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Probably the latter, but SQL (databases) don't "serve traffic" they serve or service requests.

Comment: When you say that DB server "serves traffic" it means that it's on-line and actively receives requests and provides responses.

Comment: This probably belongs on https://ell.stackexchange.com/ - but please check their Help Centre for tips on how to ask a good question there.

Comment: @IMSoP It appears that the OP is asking about a term of art rather than general language usage. That said, I'm not sure what site would make the most sense, though I feel the OP has asked a fair question.

Comment: @Stu It seems something is missing in your answer: "they serve... what? ...or service requests. PM 77-1, I guess you're right as "traffic" can go both ways. Thanks!

Comment: @PauloR.Koronfli you seem mistaken, I have not posted an answer, merely a comment  - serve in that context is a verb.